# Reactive Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an interactive shiny application that displays a leaflet plot based on a user's date and plot type specification. Ideally, I would like the user to specify whether they would like to view a state-wide or a county-wide plot. Then, based on their answers, I would like them to decide whether to use the regular data or the standardized data. After this, they would hit a submit button and the plot would render. I don't want the plot to render until the user presses the "Submit" action button. This is my idea so far, but it fails whenever I try to implement.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shapefiles)
library(sp)
library(CARBayes)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

## County Data
dta <- read.csv()

## County Data (percentage)
perc <-read.csv()

## Date Specification Function
selectdates <- function(data, start, end){
    keep <- data[, 1:5]
    data <- data[, -c(1:5)]
    tmp1 <- as.Date(names(data))
    tmp2 <- which(tmp1 >= as.Date(start) & tmp1 <= as.Date(end))
    tmp <- data[, tmp2]
    Sum <- rowSums(tmp)
    tmp <- cbind(keep, Sum)
    return(tmp)
}


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Mapping"),
    tags$em(""),
    tags$hr(),
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date Range:",
                           start = as.character(Sys.Date() - 6),
                           end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
            selectInput("ptChoice", "Type of Plot:", choices = c("", "County-Wise", "State-Wise")),
            selectInput("typeChoice", "Data Type:", choices = c("", "Raw", "Percentage")),
            actionButton("submitButton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
        ),
        
        # Display leaflet plot of cases
        mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("countyPlot"),
            leafletOutput("statePlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$ptChoice, {
        req(input$ptchoice)
        if(input$ptChoice == "County-Wide"){
            hide("statePlot")
            show("countyPlot")
        }
        else{
            hide("countyPlot")
            show("statePlot")
        }
    })
    
    fdta <- eventReactive(input$typeChoice, {
        if (input$typeChoice == "Raw"){
            df <- selectdates(data = tmp, start = input$daterange[1], end = input$daterange[2])
            row.names(df) <- df$FIPS
        }else if (input$typeChoice == "Percentage"){
            df <- selectdates(data = perc, start = input$daterange[1], end = input$daterange[2])
        }else {return(NULL)}
        df
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$submitButton, {
        output$statePlot <- renderLeaflet({
            ## INSERT STATE PLOT CODE HERE
        })
        output$countyPlot <- renderLeaflet({

            ## Loads SHP and DBF File
            shp <- read.shp()
            dbf <- read.dbf()
            
            sp <- combine.data.shapefile(data = fdta, shp = shp, dbf = dbf)
            proj4string(sp) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
            sp <- spTransform(sp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
            
            colours <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = sp@data$Sum)
            
            leaflet(sp) %>%
                addTiles() %>%
                addPolygons(
                    fillColor = ~ colours(Sum),
                    weight = 1,
                    opacity = 0.7,
                    color = "white",
                    dashArray = '3',
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    highlight = highlightOptions(
                        weight = 5,
                        color = "#666",
                        dashArray = "",
                        fillOpacity = 0.7,
                        bringToFront = TRUE
                    )
                ) %>%
                addLegend(
                    pal = colours,
                    values = sp@data$Sum,
                    opacity = 1,
                    title = "Count"
                ) %>%
                addScaleBar(position = "bottomleft")
        })
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the two plots inside an `observeEvent`, if you want it only after someone clicks on submit button.  To use the appropriate dataframe, create a reactive dataframe and then use it as `dfa()` to generate the appropriate plot.  Try this

```
server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$ptChoice,{
      req(input$ptChoice)
      if(input$ptChoice == "County-Wide"){
        hide("statePlot")
        show("countyPlot")
      }else{
        hide("countyPlot")
        show("statePlot")
      }
    })
    
    dfa <- eventReactive(input$typechoice, {
      if (input$typechoice == "Regular") {
        df <- dta
      }else if (input$typechoice == "Standardized") {
        df <- dta2
      }else {return(NULL)}
      df
    })

    observeEvent(input$submitButton,{
      output$stateplot <- renderLeaflet({
        state <- CODE FOR STATE PLOT
      })
      output$countyPlot <- renderLeaflet({
        county <- CODE FOR COUNTY PLOT
      })
    })

  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I need it to do. I do have a question though, how could I incorporate the "regular vs. standardized" data portion into this?

Comment: @JoseAlfaro, please see the updated code.  Use eventReactive to select the appropriate dataframe.

Comment: I see what is being done here, but when I enter dfa as my dataset into my leaflet plot function I get the error "Error: invalid 'times' argument". Let me update my code on here so hopefully you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Please change `data = fdta` to `data = fdta()`

Comment: Ah! You are the absolute best. Thank you so much for your assistance tonight! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have your `leaflet` plot be stored in `reactiveValues` (`rv`) - then, you can have one `output` for your plot, and show what is stored in `rv`.

To change the plot when the submit button is pressed, be sure to reference the `input$submitButton` with your `observeEvent`.

Here is a working example that can be adapted. You could use an additional function to generate the plots based on your input values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Leaflet Plot"),
  tags$em(""),
  tags$hr(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("plotChoice", "Type of Plot:", choices = c("", "Boston", "Chicago")),
      actionButton("submitButton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
    ),
    # Display leaflet plot of cases
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("leafletPlot")
    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(plot = NULL)
  
  output$leafletPlot <- renderLeaflet({
    rv$plot
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submitButton, {
    if (input$plotChoice == "Boston") {
      rv$plot <- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -71.0589, lat = 42.3601, zoom = 12) %>% addTiles()
    } else {
      rv$plot <- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -87.6298, lat = 41.8781, zoom = 12) %>% addTiles()
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```